# Tabla HTML con celdas de varios colores

Tags: php, html, css

de nuevo con dudas...

tengo una tabla en la que las celdas, normalmente van coloreadas dependiendo del sitio donde ha estado un trabajador... hasta aquí todo bien....

```
"<td bgcolor='".$colorFondo1."'align='center' width='40'>"."<font color='Blue'><b>".$horas1."</td>".
```

Pero un trabajador, a veces, ha estado en dos lugares diferentes, por lo que la celda debería tener dos colores....

con Css, sé que es posible, pero indicandole colores fijos, no se como modificar esto, para pasarle al css las variables correspondientes a los colores que necesito, ó si se puede hacer de otra forma...

a ver si me dais alguna idea.

Gracias...

Comment: Osea que la misma celda se pinte de dos colores a la vez

Answer (score 0):

Usar atributos como `bgcolor`, `align` y `color` ya no es aconsejable  desde [HTML 4.01](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/graphics.html#adef-bgcolor) (dejando detalles de formato al CSS). Se deberia usar estilos como `background-color`, `text-align` y `color` en su lugar.
Mas comodo y elegante aun es trabajar con **clases CSS** y luego simplemente definir en un archivo de estilo los colores y cualquier otro detalle de diseño:

```
<td class='tablecell onecolor' ><span class='bluetext'>".$horas1."</span></td>
```

Y el css seria

```
<style>
.tablecell{
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
}
.onecolor {
  background-color: #FF8;
}
.bluetext{
  color: blue;
}
</style>
```

Ahora para un doble color de fondo podria usarse `linear-gradient()` en `background-image` (no `background-color`)

```
<td class='tablecell twocolor' ><span class='bluetext'>".$horas1."</span></td>
```

y el CSS adicional:

```
.twocolor {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg,#FF8,#F8F);
}
```

Tambien peudes usar un mombre de clase con una `$variable` , y luego definir su formato en CSS:

```
<td class='tablecell ".$cell_class."' ><span class='bluetext'>".$horas1."</span></td>
```

Si quieres agregar el estilo "en-linea"usando el atributo `style` para controlar los colores directamente:

```
"<td class='tablecell' style='background-color:linear-gradient(90deg,".$color1.",".$color2.")' ><span class='bluetext'>".$horas1."</span></td>"
```

Y si quieres usar solo un color, deja que `$color1` y `$color2` tengan el mismo valor.

**EDIT** *(autor de la pregunta)*

He seguido estos consejos, pero no colorea la celda con los dos colores, me la deja en blanco, tengo esto para probar:

```
$color1="#FF8";
$color2="#F8F";
```

Luego la celda:

```
"<td class='tablecell' style='background-color:linear-gradient(90deg,".$color1.",".$color2.")' ><span class='bluetext'>".$horas1."</span></td>"
```

todo me parece correcto, pero no pone los dos colores....

el CSS

```
<style>
.tablecell{
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.onecolor {
  background-color: #FF8;
}
.bluetext{
  color: blue;
}
.select {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
  

</style>
```

Comment: Obsoletos no, pues el navegador los sigue interpretando, lo que si es que su uso está desaconsejado por ser una mala práctica

Comment: algo como esto....twocolor {
  background-color: linear-gradient(90deg,$color1,$color2);
}

Comment: @Aldeano agregué mas informacion si lo quieres hacer directamente en la fila

Comment: gracias por la aclaracion, me di cuenta de un detalle, para usar linear gradient debe asignarse a background-image, no background-color (ej: `background-image:linear-gradient(...)`)

Answer (score 0):

F.Igor, he probado tus recomendaciones, pero no me hace el gradiente, he probado otras formulas y nada, que no hay manera...

El CSS

```
<style>
.tablecell{
  text-align: center;
  width: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.onecolor {
  background-color: #FF8;
}
.bluetext{
  color: blue;
}

 .twocolor {
  background-color: linear-gradient(90deg,#FF8,#F8F);
}



.select {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 120px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
}
  

}

</Style>
```

la Celda..... probando antes de usar variables....

```
"<td class='tablecell' style='background-color: linear-gradient(#FF8,#F8F)' ><span class='bluetext'>".$horas1."</span></td>"
```

Pues Nada, que el gradiente no sale....lo demás.. OK

alguna idea??

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le ocurre lo mismo, de esta forma funciona.....

```
solo background:
"<td class='tablecell' style='background:linear-gradient(90deg,".$color1.",".$color2.")' ><span class='bluetext'>".$horas1."</span></td>"
```